# Is it possible to get sum of multiplication of three serieses when sum of every combination of two serieses is present?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

Let's say I have this function $$f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i * y_i$$ and I have the values of $f(A,A)$, $f(A,B)$, $f(A,C)$, f(B,B), ... . Can I somehow get the value of $$f(A,B,C) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i * B_i * C_i$$?

I tried applying "mutated" dot product identity:
$$f(A,B,C) = \sqrt{f(A,A)f(B,B)f(C,C)}\cos\theta$$ but couldn't think how to get $\cos\theta$.

NOTE: I think it's related to the dot product above, because when I isolate it, it's value is between $-1$ and $1$.

The actual serieses' values is not present. They all have the same size, and they don't have\share property.

Comment: If you by denoting the upper limit as "?" mean that it is some finite, but unknown number, then simply call it $n$ (or something similar) and say that $n$ is unknown.

Comment: How does $x$ as the input variable relate to $x_i$ in the formula?

Comment: @Lovsovs Those are serieses. Bad notation from me I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot recover the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i z_i$$
from the sums
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2,\quad \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i,\quad \ldots,\quad \sum_{i=1}^\infty z_i^2.$$

To see this, suppose that we have the sequences

$$x: 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$$
$$y: 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$$
$$z: 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$$

then we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty z_i^2 = 2$$
and $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i z_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i z_i = 1$$
as inputs, from which we want the output
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i z_i = 0$$

On the other hand, consider the sequences
$$x' : 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$$
$$y' : 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$$
$$z' : 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots$$

again we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty (x'_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (y'_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (z'_i)^2 = 2$$
and $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x'_i y'_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x'_i z'_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty y'_i z'_i = 1$$
as inputs, but this time
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x'_i y'_i z'_i = 1$$

You may find it instructive to read about [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)).